# Dynamically generated radio button dont work

Tags: php, html

I am generating radio buttons dynamically by PHP but it is not working .I am not able to uncheck a radio button once checked and once I select the other radio button with same name other is not automaticaly unchecked .

```
echo "<form action="."".">";
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Reg Num</th>

<th>Select</th>
<th>Reject</th>
</tr>";


/* <th>Name</th>
<th>State</th>
<th>Constituency</th> */

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
 // echo "<td>" . $row['voter_id'] . "</td>";
 //       echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
 //  echo "<td>" . $row['state'] . "</td>";
 //   echo "<td>" . $row['constituency'] . "</td>";
 echo  "<td>" . $row['numreg'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td><input type="."radio"." name=".$row['voter_id']. "value="."1"."></td>";
    echo    "<td><input type="."radio"." name=".$row['voter_id'] ."value="."2"."></td>";
    echo "</tr>";



  }
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: For that the name of your radio button must be same.

Answer (score 2):

try following

```
echo "<form action=''>";
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Reg Num</th>

<th>Select</th>
<th>Reject</th>
</tr>";


/* <th>Name</th>
<th>State</th>
<th>Constituency</th> */

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
 // echo "<td> $row['voter_id']</td>";
 //       echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
 //  echo "<td>" . $row['state'] . "</td>";
 //   echo "<td>" . $row['constituency'] . "</td>";
 echo  "<td>" . $row['numreg'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td><input type='radio' name='voter_id' value='$row[voter_id]'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='radio' name='voter_id' value='$row[voter_id]'></td>";
    echo "</tr>";



  }
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
```

Answer (score 1):

For that the name of your radio button must be same.Change your code like the following inside the while loop where you are creating the radio buttons

```
 echo '<td><input type="radio" name="voter_id" id="'.$row["voter_id"]. '"value="1"></td>';
 echo '<td><input type="radio" name="voter_id" id="'.$row["voter_id"] .'"value="2"></td>';
```

Comment: Your answer helped me for making what I wanted to make .thanks .

Answer (score 0):

We dont need `double quotes` for the type.Try like

```
echo "<td><input type='radio' name='".$row['voter_id']. "' value='1' "></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did this and it worked

```
echo '<td><input type="radio" name="'.$row["voter_id"]. '"value="1"></td>';
echo '<td><input type="radio" name="'.$row["voter_id"] .'"value="2"></td>';
```